# Access a javascript variable in another js file in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I do have a HomeRoute.js file in application which has BackBone.Model.extend implementation . I'm calling an ajax in the render method of this HomeRoute.js which provides me the session json. Now from this json i want to extract an variable sessionId and i want to use this sessionId variable in another HeaderView.js file.

I researched a lot on this but couldn't find any way to pass this variable to the HeaderView.js

HomeRoute.js code

```
var HomeRoute = BackBone.Model.extend({
render: function() { 

 this.createSession("userId","tenantId","orgId","accountNumb"); 
},

createSession : function(userId, tenantId, orgUnit, userAccountNum) {
var self = this;
var showHtml = function(data){
           if(data.status == "valid"){
           var sessionId = data.session.sessionId;// This variable to be used in another js file
           self.displayHtml(self, sessionId);   
           }else{
                //  To be implemented Later
           }
    }
    $.ajax({
         type : 'post',
         url : "url",
         success : showHtml,
         error : function(){
        alert("An Error Occurred while creating session");
         }
    });
},
```

Any lead would be very much helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways of doing this.

I'd just create a variable outside of HomeRoute (in the same file) called sessionId (right now you only have that variable in the showHtml function, within the HomeRoute object; move it much higher in the scope).  Any variable at that very top scope can be seen by other .js files included after this one, including your HeaderView.js file.

For example:

```
var sessionId;

var HomeRoute = BackBone.Model.extend({
render: function() { 

 this.createSession("userId","tenantId","orgId","accountNumb"); 
},

createSession : function(userId, tenantId, orgUnit, userAccountNum) {
var self = this;
var showHtml = function(data){
           if(data.status == "valid"){
           sessionId = data.session.sessionId;// This variable to be used in another js file
           self.displayHtml(self, sessionId);   
           }else{
                //  To be implemented Later
           }
    }
    $.ajax({
         type : 'post',
         url : "url",
         success : showHtml,
         error : function(){
        alert("An Error Occurred while creating session");
         }
    });
},
```

Then in the other file (HeaderView.js, included -after- HomeRoute.js), you can simply access that variable:

```
alert(sessionId);
```

...assuming the post function has already returned, of course.  (And also assuming that you can change a variable outside the scope of an object in JS, which I'm not positive about.  If not, you're going to have to return the value from the instantiated HomeRoute object and assign it to sessionId.)

Comment: Thanks Leng. Can you also show the way to include HomeRoute.js in HeaderView.js.

Comment: @rkj You don't need to do that.  You can just include them both in the same HTML page, HomeRoute first.

Answer (score 0):

If sessionId is a critical part of HomeRoute, you can make it as part of the model and initialize it under the initializer:

```
var HomeRoute = BackBone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() { 
        this.sessionId = null;
    },
...
}
```

and have it updated under 'showHtml':

```
var showHtml = function(data){
           if(data.status == "valid"){
           self.sessionId = data.session.sessionId;// This variable to be used in another js file
           self.displayHtml(self, sessionId);   
           }else{
                //  To be implemented Later
           }
    }
```

You will need to export the model object in your view file to get access to sessionId

```
var _homeRoute = new HomeRoute ();
var _sid = _homeRoute.sessionId;
```